# What is Landau Ramanujan constant?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, mathematicians, ramanujan-summation

What is Landau Ramanujan constant? I searched on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant) but explanation was not clear enough please explain it along with example thank you

Comment: Do you know the Euler product of the Dedekind zeta function of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ ?

Comment: An example is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799979/how-many-integers-leq-n-are-a-sum-of-two-squares-as-n-to-infty). In Andrew Kelley's answer $s(12)=7$ because $1=1^2+0^2, 2=1^2+1^2, 4=2^2+0^2, 5=2^2+1^2, 8=2^2+2^2, 9=3^2+0^2, 10= 3^2+1^2$. So there are $7$ numbers less than $12$ that can be written as the sum of two squares. A natural question to ask "is how many numbers less than $x$ can be written as the sum of two squares?" 
The answer is (as x gets large) $bx/\sqrt{\ln(x)}$ where $b$ is LR constant.

Comment: Thank you so much copper hat